# Can a class behave differently based on the context it's used within?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop

My problem is that I want to use one class in two classes but there will be properties that shouldn't exist in one of them. For example a warehouse ships items to the branches, the item in the branch should have `DiscountPercentage` property but it doesn't exist in the warehouse. Also there is a connection between the two instances of items in both classes (`Warehouse` and `Branch`): when items are added to a branch the quantity should be subtracted from the quantity (property) in the warehouse.

I'm thinking of the OOP concepts, how it can help, but I'm totally confused.
I created a class for the Item:

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [Range(0, 100), Display(Name = "Discount Percentage"), RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Enter only numeric number")]
        public double? DiscountPercentage { get; set; } = 0;
        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    }

public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

 public class Warehouse
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem in my code is that the item in the warehouse is the same as in the branch's, which is not true and also not wrong, how OOP can handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In proper class design, the `DiscountPercentage` is not a property of the item. It’s also not a property of the branch. Instead, it’s a property of the *relation* between the branch and an item:

[image: UML diagram of explained class relationships]

So what you would do is create some `BranchItem` type which essentially just sits between them and defines the relationship including additional properties:

```
public class BranchItem
{
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public double DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This will be the joining table, right? in this case I'll need `BranchId` and `ItemId` properties?

Comment: In databases this will be a joining table, yes. How the link is realized in the database depends a bit on your ORM, but you can choose to add those ids to the link, yes. I left out that part deliberately to only speak in a pure object oriented design context.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, which tool you used to draw the diagram?

Comment: @Mohamed I’m using the awesome and lightweight open source tool [Umlet](http://www.umlet.com/) for UML diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

One wonders if you actually need `Branch` and `Warehouse` objects at all, or whether each item could simply have a property `location`.

In any case, the OO way to solve the problem as stated is to create a new class, say, `WarehouseItem` which contains everything that a `Warehouse` should be able to access in an `Item`. Then, extend `WarehouseItem` with `Item` and add whatever properties you need in `Branch`. Inside `Warehouse`, you should only interact with `WarehouseItem`s, even if the objects are actually of type `Item`. This is pretty textbook [polymorphism](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/P/polymorphism.html).

(One caveat: Generally you would want the simpler class with less properties to have the more generic name i.e. `Item` and the extension with more properties to have a more specific name. So, my example is not perfect.)

Comment: IMO that link sucks, why not link to the MSDN page for [polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

Comment: I’m not sure if you got OP’s intentions right (well, I hope I did…). A warehouse can have items and those items are shipped to possibly multiple branches. So an item can be offered by multiple branches (the same item), but each branch can get a different discount for that item. I’m not sure how polymorphism would help here since you would not want to introduce multiple separately typed copies of a single item.

Comment: @Quantic I literally googled "oo polymorphism" and grabbed the first result. But you're right, that link isn't great. Still, I think if this is a problem you struggle with then the light reading there might be easier reading than the relevant MSDN or oracle page.

Comment: @poke Was I off base? Each item has its own member variable for discount, but they aren't exposed to the warehouse object since it only sees them as the parent class, `WarehouseItem`. The branch, upon receiving a `WarehouseItem`, would cast it back to `Item`. E.g. the factory creates a `Item`, sends it to warehouse which casts it to `WarehouseItem`, which sends it to a branch which casts it back to `Item`.